# Can a Restful API be built with AWS Restful API and Step Functions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-step-functions

I have the task to build a regular UI backend API. A JSON request is sent, some logic executed and half a second later a JSON response will be returned.
The natural way of building that is API GW invoking a Python Lambda and all logic is executed in that single Lambda function.

But the graphical way of orchestrating Step Functions has some appeal as well. So the idea is that API GW invokes an Express Step Function, which has Choice, Parallel and Lambda tasks.

I know that Step Functions are used for Workflows and events. But a API GW request can be seen as event and orchestrating multiple lambdas is a workflow. So technically it is possible.

Differences I can see between these two approaches are

- Reuse code (libraries, Lambda Layer) vs. reuse Lambda instances
- Use multi threading vs. Parallel Step Function Tasks
- Modify the sequence of operations in code vs. modify it in the Step Function
- Methods calls run at CPU speed vs Lambda invocation at network speed
- 1 API call = 1 Lambda vs 1 API call = Step Function plus 10 Lambda invocations (Quotas, Throttling, cold start time, probability of failure)

Some statistics:
The code consists of 10 methods/lambdas, most of which are to be executed in parallel. Code is rather on the simple side and consists mostly of calling other Restful APIs and waiting for their return. Higher degree of elasticity needed.

Comment: Asking for opinions is [explicitly discouraged here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask); is there a way you can frame your question to ask something more concrete?

Comment: Rephrased the question

Comment: The problem with "can it be built" is that you seem to have answered it yourself - it's _possible_ to implement it that way, but then lots of things are _possible_. Try to work backwards: what would you consider a *good answer* to your question? Or maybe what you want *is* just a discussion with someone about the pros and cons, which is fine, but unfortunately this isn't the place to have that discussion.

Comment: I find the use of step functions for UI backends the most stupid thing to do. So I am looking for somebody who did that successfully and if there are regrets.

Comment: So essentially, I would like to know if I am biased against step functions or if I am missing something.

Comment: Why do you think using Step Functions is a bad idea. Its actually a good way to chain AWS Services calls together to perform a given use case.

Answer (score 1):

"Can a Restful API be built with AWS Restful API and Step Functions" The answer is Yes. More Explanation below...

There is a similar example of what you are asking in [AWS Code Lib](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/what-is-code-library.html). In this example, HTTP requests are sent to API Gateway from a React client which puts an image into a S3 bucket that triggers a Step Functions workflow.

[image]

This example application analyzes and stores customer feedback cards. Specifically, it fulfills the need of a fictitious hotel in New York City. The hotel receives feedback from guests in various languages in the form of physical comment cards. That feedback is uploaded into the app through a web client. After an image of a comment card is uploaded, the following steps occur within Step Functions:

- Text is extracted from the image using Amazon Textract.
- Amazon Comprehend determines the sentiment of the extracted text and
  its language.
- The extracted text is translated to English using Amazon Translate.
- Amazon Polly synthesizes an audio file from the extracted text.

This example is implemented using various AWS SDKs:

[Create an application that analyzes customer feedback and synthesizes audio](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/comprehend_example_cross_FSA_section.html)